# Understanding of Proposition of Limit

Tags: real-analysis

*Prop.* Let {$x_{n}$} be a sequence such that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }x_{n}=x\neq 0$. Then there is a $\delta>0$ and $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that

$\left| x_{n}\right| >\delta$ for all $n\geq N$.

In particular, $x_{n}$ assumes that the value $0$ only finitely times.

**Is there a mistake in the proposition?** I think, it should be $\left| x_{n}\right| <\delta$ for all $n\geq N$.

Answer (score 1):

No.Observe that $|x_n| \to |x|>0$. Take  $\delta =|x|/2$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of limit there is $N$ such that for $n\ge N$ we have $\vert x_n-x\vert< \frac{\vert x\vert}{2}$. Now by the triangle inequality:

$$\vert x\vert -\vert x_n\vert <\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}\iff \vert x_n\vert>\delta=\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The key result is this:
$$
||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b| 
$$
for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove the proposition, note that $x_{n} \to x$ and $x \neq 0$ imply that there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{n}-x| < |x|/2$ for all $n \geq N$.
Note that $||x_{n}|-|x|| \leq |x_{n} - x|$ for all $n \geq N$, so
$|x_{n}| - |x| > -|x|/2$ for all $n \geq N$,
and hence
$|x_{n}| > |x|/2$ for all $n \geq N$.